# runTest is not working correctly in Android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, mockk

I am getting strange issue using `runTest`. I have a simple viewModel

```
class LoadingViewModel(
    private val ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher,
) : ViewModel() {

 // more function in here

    var xyz by mutableStateOf(false)
    fun checkXyz() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            delay(1000L)
            xyz = true
        }
    }
}
```

**LoadingViewModelTest**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
class LoadingViewModelTest {

    private val subject by lazy {
        spyk(LoadingViewModel(UnconfinedTestDispatcher()))
    }

@Before
    fun setUp() {
        MockKAnnotations.init(this, relaxed = true)
    }

    @Test
    fun `xyz - when method called then should assign value on xyz`() = runTest {

        subject.checkXyz()
        verify {
            subject.xyz = true
        }
    }
}
```

I am using `junit4` with kotlin `1.8.10`

**Getting error**

```
Verification failed: call 1 of 1: LoadingViewModel(#3).setXyz(eq(true))) was not called.

Calls to same mock:
1) LoadingViewModel(#3).checkXyz()
2) LoadingViewModel(#3).getTag(androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelCoroutineScope.JOB_KEY)
3) LoadingViewModel(#3).setTagIfAbsent(androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelCoroutineScope.JOB_KEY, androidx.lifecycle.CloseableCoroutineScope@2d5580f6)
```

I checked and If removed `delay` it working fine.

**UPDATE**

After adding `ioDispatcher` in `viewModelScope` I am getting same above error

```
fun checkXyz() {
     viewModelScope.launch(ioDispatcher) {
        delay(1000L)
        xyz = true
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `checkXyz()` doesn't really do what you expect in your test. So either your test is not correct or your implementation of `checkXyz()`.

`checkXyz()` assigns the value asynchronously, in the background. This is because it uses `viewModelScope.launch()`. As such, we should not expect the value is assigned straight after calling `checkXyz()`. It could happen somewhere in the future, but we don't know when exactly.

If your idea was that after returning from `checkXyz()` the value is assigned already, then you should use a suspend function instead and don't use `viewModelScope.launch()`. But if you really meant this function to run asynchronously, then you can't test its effects easily as you don't know when the asynchronous operation finishes. You would have to return a `Job` object from it to observe the operation in the background and wait for it to finish:

```kotlin
runTest {
    subject.checkXyz().join()
    verify {
        subject.xyz = true
    }
}

fun checkXyz(): Job {
     return viewModelScope {
        delay(1000L)
        xyz = true
     }
 }
```

However, if the "standard" usage of this function is to wait for it to finish, then it should be really a suspend function.

Comment: How do we know job is finished? Can you provide the example?

Answer (score 1):

You're passing in a dispatcher to the ViewModel but not actually using it in the view model's code. So it's using its own dispatcher that your test does not know about.

Use the dispatcher given to the ViewModel (which is the test one in the test)

```
viewModelScope.launch(ioDispatcher) { ... }
```

Comment: I am getting same error, nothing works.